# issues with downloading project files from git

Tags: git, laravel-4, github-for-windows

when i try to clone this repository:

```
git clone git@github.com:laravel/laravel.git
```

I get this error:

```
"Cloning into 'laravel'...  
Permission denied (publickey).  
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  

Please make sure you have the correct access rights  
and the repository exists."
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I am a newbie to both git and laravel, i am trying to practice what i saw in the "Laravel Application Development Cookbook."

Answer (score 1):

It may happen your `public/private` key pair missing from your local or your using different machine to connect/clone the repo. In that case ...

first start by setting up your own public/private key pair set. You can use rsa key, On most systems you can generate by typing `ssh-keygen`.

But first you want to make sure you cd into your .ssh directory. Open up the terminal and run:

```
cd ~/.ssh && ssh-keygen
```

next you need to copy this to your clipboard.

```
On Linux run: cat id_rsa.pub | xclip
```

Add your key to your github account via the website.
finally setup your git config

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```

That's it you should be good to clone and checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Works the same here!

Use this command instead:
git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Comment: what is the meaning `Permission denied (publickey)`.